# Inequality for $1<p<2$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, convex-analysis

I know the following algebraic inequality holds. For any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$, there exists a positive constant $C$ such that
$$
|x|^p\geq |y|^p+p|y|^{p-2}y(x-y)+C\frac{|x-y|^2}{(|x|+|y|)^{2-p}},\text{ for }1<p<2.
$$
I did not get the following step. Assumption(A): If there exists $t_0\in[0,1]$ such that $t_0 x+(1-t_0)y=0$, then the above inequality easily follows.

What I can check is that due to the convexity of $|x|^p$, for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$
$$
|x|^p\geq |y|^p+p|y|^{p-2}y(x-y),\text{ for }1<p<2.
$$
But did not the how the above follows under the assumption (A).

Comment: What is $C(p)$?

Comment: Thanks. It's a positive constant. I have just edited the question.

Comment: What happens if $x=y$?

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question. Please consider the $|x|^p$ in place of $F$ above.